# Text is "undefined" in MongoDB instead file data is successfully uploaded

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, axios, multer

I'm playing around with MERN, and developing images uploader website. I was trying to upload an image with text which comes from input from React. I could upload successfully. However, the text is un "undefined". here is my try.

```
//React//
const Landing = () => {
  const [imageState, setImageState] = useState({
    text: "",
    image: null,
    redirect: false
  });
  const onChange = e => {
   setImageState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

 const upload = e => {
      formData.append("myimage", image);
      formData.append("text", text);
      await axios.post("/upload", formData);

      <form
        onSubmit={e => upload(e)}/>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
        />
        <input type="file" name="myimage" onChange={e => imageChange(e)} />
        {/* {renderRedirect()} */}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" />

//Node//
router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }

    let data = new ImageModel({
      text: req.body.text,
      image: req.file.originalname
    });
    data.save().then(result => {
      res.send(result);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setImageState method I'm not sure e.target.name will work when setting the field parameter. Try e.target.id instead. Example:

```js
setImageState({
  [e.target.id]: e.target.value
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It doesn't work. what I realized is this part seems not to work properly. Because the input element doesnt have id, however it still allow to update input.